# How to insert the last id from a table into another table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to take the id of the most recent item in a database, increment it by one and insert that new id in to another table.

I tried:

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tableName ORDER BY id DESC");

while ($return = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)) {

   $id = $return['id'];
   $newId = $id++;

}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO anotherTable (someColumn) VALUES ('$newId')");
```

But it didn't work. How can this be done?

Comment: Why do you need it? why don't you use autoincrement feature?

Comment: Is there a specific error message? Also $newId will equal $id here. `$id++` will only increment the value of $id AFTER the assignment occurs.

Comment: @ Col. Shrapnel I do use auto increment, this is for another purpose altogether.

Comment: It shouldn't be for another purpose as it can ruin database integrity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tableName ORDER BY id DESC");

if(! $select)
    die("Query Failed");

$return = mysql_fetch_assoc($select);
$id = $return['id'];
$newId = ++ $id; // post increment does not work...use preincrement.
mysql_query("INSERT INTO anotherTable (someColumn) VALUES ('$newId')");
```

Comment: Great, thanks I needed to remove the while. For some odd reason $newId = $id++ doesn't work but $newId = $id + 1 does.

Answer (score 4):

You should not do this. Instead insert a new record into `tableName` then use [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to capture the new ID and then insert it into `anotherTable`. This way you avoid race conditions that could happen if you did it the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a while statement? If you only want the most recent id, just take the while out..

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tableName ORDER BY id DESC");

$return = mysql_fetch_assoc($select);

$id = $return['id'];
$newId = $id + 1;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO anotherTable (someColumn) VALUES ('$newId')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql_insert_id() to get the last inserted ID